# Was ist »Österreichisch«? (sprachwissenschaftlich)

Tags: meaning, austrian

Gelegentlich liest man hier auf German.stackexchange Fragen und Antworten, in denen es darum geht, ob ein bestimmtes Wort ein österreichisches Wort sein könnte. Aber auch außerhalb dieses Forums scheint unklar zu sein, was genau mit *»Österreichisch«* gemeint sein soll. Häufig, vor allem in deutschländischen Medien (aber nicht nur dort), wird der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* als Gegensatz zum Begriff *»Hochdeutsch«* verwendet. Hier sind einige Beispiele dafür:

> Um den Wortschatz Austrias auch künftig lebendig zu halten, soll ab sofort in den Klassenzimmern Memory gespielt werden: mit Karten, die verschiedene Begriffe auf Hochdeutsch, Schweizer Deutsch und österreichischem Deutsch benennen und voneinander abgrenzen.
> <sup>[der Spiegel, 2014](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/oesterreich-geht-gegen-hochdeutsch-vor-a-973490.html)</sup>
>
> Hochdeutsch und Österreichisch - Zuordnungsübung
> <sup>[mercer.edu](http://faculty.mercer.edu/weintraut_ej/style/Austrian1.htm)</sup>
>
> Deutsch und Österreichisch unterscheiden sich mehr voneinander, als man zunächst glaubt.
> <sup>[Zeit online, 2018](https://www.zeit.de/zett/2018-11/diese-woerter-musst-du-kennen-wenn-du-in-oesterreich-ernst-genommen-werden-willst?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)</sup>
>
> Die österreichische Sprache wird nach und nach vom Hochdeutschen verdrängt.
> <sup>[n-tv.de, 2012](https://www.n-tv.de/wissen/Osterreichisch-wandelt-sich-Hochdeutsch-setzt-sich-mehr-und-mehr-durch-article6939841.html)</sup>
>
> Grosso modo vertraten die Diskussionspartner die Auffassung, lediglich das bundesdeutsche Deutsch sei "echtes Hochdeutsch", Österreichisch lediglich ein hässlicher Dialekt desselben.
> <sup>[Wiener Zeitung, 2021](https://www.wienerzeitung.at/meinung/gastkommentare/2123248-Das-Verblassen-des-Oesterreichischen.html)</sup>
>
> Das Österreichische wird vermehrt vom hochdeutschen Sprachgebrauch in den Medien beeinflusst.
> <sup>[mein-oesterreich.info](https://www.mein-oesterreich.info/wissenswertes/oesterreichisches-deutsch.htm)</sup>

Das lässt vermuten, dass *»Österreichisch«* so etwas wie ein deutscher Dialekt ist. Ist das so? Wenn nicht: Was genau ist *»Österreichisch«* denn dann?

Answer (score 5):

### Kurze Antwort:

Der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* wird in unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen verwendet und ist sprachwissenschaftlich nicht definiert. Man sollte ihn daher am besten gar nicht verwenden.

Es gibt aber [Österreichisches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch), das ist eine der drei gleichwertigen Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache. Die beiden anderen Standardvarietäten sind: [Deutsches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesdeutsches_Hochdeutsch) (oft auch "Bundesdeutsches Deutsch" genannt) und [Schweizerisches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizer_Hochdeutsch), das man auf keinem Fall mit [Schweizerdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch) verwechseln darf. Wie schon erwähnt, sind alle drei Standardvarietäten gleichwertig, Insbesondere sind alle drei Ausprägungen von *»Hochdeutsch«,* wobei der Begriff *»Hochdeutsch«* selbst auch mehrdeutig ist, und in dem hier gemeinten Kontext besser durch *»Standarddeutsch«* ersetzt werden sollte.

Natürlich werden in Österreich auch Dialekte gesprochen. Es gibt aber keinen Dialekt, der *»Österreichisch«* heißt. Die in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte unterscheiden sich stark voneinander und werden üblicherweise nach dem Bundesland benannt, in dem sie gesprochen werden (Vorarlbergerisch, Oberösterreichisch, usw.). Wenn im Ausland von *»Österreichisch«* die Rede ist, und damit ein Dialekt gemeint ist, ist damit so gut wie immer Wienerisch gemeint, denn in der [Metropolregion Wien](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballungsraum_Wien) leben derzeit rund 2,9 Millionen Menschen, das ist fast ein Drittel aller Österreicher. (Österreich hat 9,0 Millionen Einwohner). Außerdem ist fast immer, wenn in Film und Fernsehen ein österreichischer Dialekt zu hören ist, der Wiener Arbeiterdialekt zu hören.

---

### Im Detail:

##### Wie kam es eigentlich dazu, dass in Österreich Deutsch gesprochen wird?

Das Gebiet, auf dem sich der heutige Staat Österreich erstreckt, war im Frühmittelalter, in dem sich anderenorts bereits Althochdeutsch belegen lässt, östlich von Salzburg und Villach noch von Slawen bevölkert. (Beispielsweise ist der Name der Stadt *Graz* ist eine Verkürzung des slowenischen Wortes *gradec = kleine Burg*). Der Westen Salzburgs und der Norden Tirols (jener Teil Tirols, der heute in Österreich liegt) wurden zu dieser Zeit von Bajuwaren bewohnt die Altbairisch sprachen, und im Süden Tirols (heutiges Südtirol, ein Teil Norditaliens) lebten Langobarden die Langobardisch sprachen. Der westlichste Zipfel des heutigen österreichischen Staatsgebiet (das Bundeslang Vorarlberg) war Siedlungsgebiet der altalemannisch sprechenden Alemannen.

Altalemannisch, Altbairisch und Langobardisch waren Altoberdeutsche Sprachen, die als Teile der Althochdeutschen Sprache angesehen werden. Langobardisch wurde von Bairisch verdrängt und starb aus, und die Bajuwaren verdrängten die Slawen bis ungefähr an die heutigen Grenzen des Staates Österreichs.

Aus diesem Grund ist die Ur-Sprache der Österreicher im Bundesland Vorarlberg Alemannisch, im Rest des Landes Bairisch. Beide Sprachen werden aber auch außerhalb Österreichs gesprochen. Alemannisch ist die Sprache der Deutsch-Schweizer, der Badener und der Schwaben, und Bairisch wird in Altbayern und in Südtirol gesprochen.

In anderen deutschsprachigen Regionen wurden andere germanische Sprachen gesprochen (Fränkisch, Sächsisch usw.). Diese Sprachen waren einander zwar sehr ähnlich, vor allem dort, wo sie geographisch aneinandergrenzten, aber wer ein paar Tagesreisen auf sich nahm, geriet dann doch in Gegenden, wo es bereits zu Verständigungsproblemen kam.

Daraus ergab sich das Bestreben, die vielen Westgermanischen Sprachen zu vereinheitlichen. Zu erwähnen ist dabei vor allem Martin Luther mit seiner deutschen Bibel, von der er wollte, dass sie überall verstanden wird wo eine deutsche Sprache gesprochen wird. Die Luther-Bibel war ein starker Motor, der die Standardisierung der deutschen Sprache vorantrieb, es gab aber auch andere Bestrebungen in diese Richtung.

Die Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Sprache ist ein Prozess, der noch nicht abgeschlossen ist, und sich gegenwärtig darin manifestiert, dass es drei unterschiedliche Standards der deutsche Sprache gibt.

##### Was ist eine Standardsprache?

Das ist eine Sprache, in der Gesetzestexte und ähnliche offizielle Dokumente verfasst werden. Eine Standardsprache wird an Schulen als eigenes Unterrichtsfach gelehrt und ist Lehr-Sprache für andere Fächer. Zeitungen und Bücher werden in Standardsprachen gedruckt, und Nachrichtensprecher großer Radio- und Fernsehanstalten sprechen in einer Standardsprache. Für Standardsprachen gibt es wohldefinierte Rechtschreibregeln, die man in Lehrbüchern nachlesen kann.

Keines dieser Kriterien trifft auf Dialekte zu, womit es eigentlich eine klare Abgrenzung zwischen modernen Standardsprachen und Dialekten gibt. Standards der deutschen Sprache gibt es aber erst seit 1876. In historischen Kontexten ist die Unterscheidung zwischen einer Sprache und einem Dialekt hingegen weit weniger klar. Auch zu erwähnen ist, dass es auch gegenwärtig Westgermanische Sprachen gibt, die nicht standardisiert sind, und bei denen es auch keine eindeutige Klarheit gibt, ob sie zu den Dialekten oder zu den Sprachen zu zählen sind. Dazu gehören vor allem Plattdeutsch und Bairisch.

##### Es gibt drei verschiedene gleichrangige Standards, Österreichisches Deutsch ist einer davon.

Dass das moderne Deutsch standardisiert ist, bedeutet aber nicht, dass es für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum einen einzigen verbindlichen Standard geben müsste. Tatsächlich schreiben die Regierungen der Staaten Deutschland, Österreich und Schweiz ihre Gesetze in drei unterschiedlichen Sprachen. So kommen beispielsweise die Wörter *»Vorfahrt«* und *»Bußgeld«* in keinem österreichischen Gesetz vor, denn dort ist die Rede von *»Vorrang«* und *»Organstrafmandat«,* und das in der Schweiz auch in Gesetzestexten zu findende Verb *»parkieren«* gibt es nur dort, während man in Österreich und Deutschland stattdessen das Verb *»parken«* verwendet.

##### Österreichisches Standarddeutsch

Der Standard, der in Österreich Anwendung findet, ist stark von der bairischen Sprache beeinflusst, die ja die Ur-Sprache von 95,5% aller Österreicher ist. Die 400.000 alemannisch sprechenden Vorarlberger machen nur knapp 4,5% der 9 Millionen Österreicher aus und leben noch dazu weiter weg von der Hauptstadt Wien als alle anderen Österreicher, aber in Wien werden die österreichischen Gesetze geschrieben, und damit wird dort festgelegt, was österreichisches Amtsdeutsch ist, und das prägt natürlich den offiziellen Standard.

##### Wird der offizielle österreichische Standard von der Bevölkerung Österreichs verwendet?

Ja und nein. Hier ist vor allem zwischen geschriebenem und gesprochenem Deutsch zu unterscheiden.

###### geschriebenes Deutsch

Das österreichische Standarddeutsch wird recht strikt in der schriftlichen Kommunikation verwendet. Alles was von Österreichern für Österreicher geschrieben wird, wird in österreichischem Standarddeutsch geschrieben. Das schließt Schulbücher und nationale und regionale Tageszeitungen mit ein. Das trifft auch auf die schriftliche Kommunikation im privaten Bereich zu, wobei hier individuelle Ausnahmen natürlich nicht auszuschließen sind. Seit schriftliche Kommunikation dank Internet aber nicht mehr zwangsweise asynchron sein muss, findet man vor allem in der synchronen schriftlichen Kommunikation (z.B. in Chats) auch vermehrt dialektale Einflüsse, weil sich synchrones Schreiben für viele mehr wie eine Art des Sprechens als des Schreibens anfühlt. (Gesprochenes österreichisches Deutsch wird weiter unten noch ausführlicher thematisiert.)

###### Bücher

Bücher, die von österreichischen Autoren geschrieben werden, werden nicht in österreichischem Deutsch geschrieben, sondern in jenem Standarddeutsch, das in Deutschland in Verwendung ist. Das gilt auch dann, wenn das Buch von einem österreichischen Verlag verlegt wird. Der Grund dafür ist ganz einfach, dass Menschen, die nicht in Österreich aufgewachsen sind (vor allem Deutsche, aber auch Schweizer), Österreichisches Deutsch in Büchern als fehlerhaft empfinden würden. Das sind aber rund 90% aller potentiellen Käufer. Die Österreicher sind es aber ebenfalls gewohnt, Bücher ausschließlich in deutschem Deutsch zu lesen.

Ausnahmen sind nur einige Kriminalromane, die in Österreich spielen. Diese Warengruppe ist aber sehr klein, und weil man auch diese Bücher gerne in Deutschland verkaufen möchte, findet man selbst in diesen Büchern kein echtes österreichisches Deutsch, sondern eine deutsch-österreichische Mischform, die von den Konsumenten in Deutschland zwar als österreichisch wahrgenommen, aber trotzdem mühelos verstanden wird.

###### gesprochenes Deutsch

Die große Mehrheit der Österreicher spricht im Alltag kein Standarddeutsch. In der Familie, unter Freunden und unter Arbeitskollegen sprechen Österreicher den jeweiligen lokalen Dialekt, der sich oftmals schon über Distanzen von 20 bis 50 km wahrnehmbar von den benachbarten Dialekten unterscheidet. Es existiert also ein Dialektkontinuum, das aber nicht auf das österreichische Staatsgebiet beschränkt ist. Die in Österreich vorherrschenden bairischen Dialekte werden, im Sinn des sich geographisch stetig wandelnden Kontinuums, auch in Italien (in Südtirol) und in weiten Teilen Bayerns gesprochen. Und auch die alemannischen Dialekte Vorarlbergs gehen nahtlos in jene der Ostschweiz und des Allgäu über.

Trotzdem werden auch die Dialekte vom jeweiligen Standarddeutsch beeinflusst. So wird beispielsweise der erste Monat des Jahres in Österreich auch in allen Dialekten *»Jänner«* genannt, während jenseits des Inn, in Bayern, der *»Jänner«* auch im Dialekt nur selten anzutreffen ist und durch den in Deutschland üblichen Namen *»Januar«* ersetzt wird. Gleiches gilt für viele Begriffspaare aus der Behördensprache, wie zum Beispiel *Vorfahrt/Vorrang,* was natürlich auf die jeweiligen Gesetzestexte zurückzuführen ist.

Das soeben gesagt betrifft aber vor allem ländliche Regionen und kleine bis mittlere Städte. In großen Städten (Graz und Linz, vor allem aber in Wien) ist die Situation aber ein wenig anders. Die in diesen Städten gesprochenen Dialekte unterscheiden sich zwar noch immer recht deutlich vom österreichischen Standarddeutsch, sind ihm aber deutlich ähnlicher als die Dialekte der ländlichen Regionen.

In Wien kommt noch ein weiteres Phänomen hinzu. Hier sprechen unterschiedliche soziale Gruppen unterschiedliche Dialekte. Der Dialekt der wohlhabenden Oberschicht ist ein ganz anderer als der Dialekt der Obdachlosen oder der Arbeiter. Dieses Phänomen ist aber weltweit in allen großen Städten anzutreffen.

###### Junge Österreicher sprechen anders als ältere

Wer heute jünger als ca. 25 Jahre ist, hat das Internet schon im Kindesalter kennengelernt und ist es gewohnt, Inhalte daraus zu konsumieren. Beliebt sind vor allem Videos von jungen InfluenzerInnen, in denen man z.B. erfährt, wie man sich zu kleiden und zu schminken hat. Wenn diese InfluenzerInnen Deutsch sprechen, stammen sie fast immer aus Deutschland und sprechen eine Sprache, die kaum dialektale Einflüsse hat und sehr stark vom Deutschen Standarddeutsch beeinflusst ist. Kinder und Jugendliche in Österreich finden diese Sprecher cool und nachahmenswert und eignen sich deren Art zu sprechen an.

Ältere Österreicher (40+) wurden aber in einer Umgebung sozialisiert, in der gesprochenes Standarddeutsch nur im Radio und Fernsehen zu hören war. Das war dann aber meist österreichisches Standarddeutsch und wurde als eine Art Fremdsprache wahrgenommen, wobei das Bedürfnis dieses Fernsehdeutsch nachzuahmen, eher gering war. Sprachlicher Kontakt fand viel häufiger im Kreis der Familie statt, wo ausschließlich Dialekt gesprochen wurde.

Aus diesem Grund vollzieht sich derzeit in Österreich durch den Generationenwechsel ein Sprachwandel in einem Ausmaß, das es kaum zuvor gegeben hat. Die Dialekt-Texte von Austropopsongs, die in den 1970er- und 80er-Jahren noch die vordersten Ränge in den österreichischen Musik-Charts belegten, werden heute von Kindern und Jugendlichen unter 20 Jahren nur mehr zum Teil verstanden.

###### Film und Fernsehen

Österreichische Filme und Fernsehproduktionen, die ausschließlich für den österreichischen Markt produziert werden, werden entweder ganz im Dialekt produziert (immer im Wiener Arbeiter-Dialekt: [Ein echter Wiener geht nicht unter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_echter_Wiener_geht_nicht_unter), [Kaisermühlen Blues](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiserm%C3%BChlen_Blues), [Kottan ermittelt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kottan_ermittelt), [MA 2412](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_2412), [Trautmann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trautmann_(Fernsehreihe))) oder in einer Mischform aus Wiener Dialekt und österreichischem Standarddeutsch, die zwar noch deutlich als Österreichisch (eigentlich Wienerisch) wahrgenommen wird, aber auch in Deutschland verstanden wird. ([Der Bockerer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Bockerer_(Film)), [Blutrausch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blutrausch_(1997)), [Komm, süßer Tod](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komm,_s%C3%BC%C3%9Fer_Tod_(Film)), [Vorstadtweiber](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorstadtweiber)). Daneben gibt es auch Filme und Serien, die österreichisches Standarddeutsch mit dialektaler Färbung verwenden ([Rotzbub](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotzbub), [Der Onkel – The Hawk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Onkel_%E2%80%93_The_Hawk))

Fremdsprachige Filme werden meist in Deutschland für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum synchronisiert, so dass man auch in österreichischen Kinos dem deutschen Deutsch nur schwer entkommen kann. Lediglich Kinderfilme bilden da Ausnahmen. In österreichischen Kinos werden die deutsche und die österreichische, manchmal aber auch nur die österreichische Version gezeigt. Von *»Arielle, die Mehrjungfrau«* gab es neben einer österreichisch-standarddeutschen Synchronisation sogar auch eine Fassung im Wiener Dialekt.

Viele Werbeclips, die auch in Deutschland zu sehen sind, wurden und werden für den österreichischen Markt in österreichischem Deutsch synchronisiert. Österreicher empfinden österreichisches Deutsch als deutlich sympathischer als deutsches Deutsch, was sich messbar auf den Konsum der beworbenen Waren auswirkt. Dabei wurde in vielen Fällen darauf verzichtet, den ausländischen Markenname auszusprechen als wäre es ein deutsches Wort. Daher wird in Österreich *Colgate* wie ein englisches Wort ausgesprochen (etwa so: *Kohlgäit*) und Michelin wie ein französisches (*Mischlöh*).

Comment: Der Satz "Alemannisch ist die Sprache der Deutsch-Schweizer und der Schwaben" sollte vielleicht ergänzt werden, so daß das keine abschließende Aufzählung ist, sonst könnten sich die Badener beschweren.

Comment: @Bodo: Danke, ich habe das nun ergänzt

Comment: Es wäre schön, wenn du deine zahlreichen Behauptungen auch mit entsprechenden Quellen belegen würdest.